# Erreur java.lang.NullPointerException in jsf managed bean

Tags: spring, jsf

Hello i have Started a spring jsf project when i run the first page jsf i recived this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.project.formation.bean.StudentBean.addStudent(StudentBean.java:31)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

can u help me and thank you !

the problem is in the jsf managed bean exactly in the addStudent() method:

```
public class StudentBean implements Serializable {
    @Autowired
    private  StudentService studentService;
    private Student student;
    public StudentBean() {
        student = new Student();
    }

    public void addStudent() {
        studentService.add(student);//line 31
        student=new Student();

    }

    public List<Student> getStudentList() {
        return studentService.findAll();
    }
    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
}
```

My Dao bean code is :

```
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void add(Student student) {
        em.persist(student);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Student> findAll() {

        Query query=em.createQuery("select s from Student s");  
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

and the complete spring xml file configuration: applicationContext.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">


<!-- bean of data source -->
    <bean id="datasource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Student"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value=""></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- bean of persistence manager -->
    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- bean definition entityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="UP_STUDENT"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <bean id="studentDao" class="com.project.formation.dao.StudentDaoImpl"/>
    <bean id="studentService" class="com.project.formation.service.StudentServiceImpl"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: public class StudentBean implements Serializable {
 @Autowired
 private  StudentService studentService;
 private Student student;
 public StudentBean() {
  student = new Student();
 }

 public void addStudent() {
  studentService.add(student);
  student=new Student();

 }
 
 public List<Student> getStudentList() {
  return studentService.findAll();
 }
 public Student getStudent() {
  return student;
 }
 public void setStudent(Student student) {
  this.student = student;
 }
}

Comment: i use this annotation for my maneged bean:
@ManagedBean(name="studentBean")@Scope@Component

Comment: Please edit your question, add the code there and mark line 31 of your StudentBean.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your StudentService is not autowired and is null, check to make sure it is annotated with @Service or @component so it is known to spring context.

generally you should mark it required=true if your app requires a bean to function.

Comment: i use @service annotation but when  I configur my bean service in the applicationContext.xml file with:
<bean id="studentDao" class="com.project.formation.dao.StudentDaoImpl"/>   the proble still not resolved
 <bean id="studentService" class="com.project.formation.service.StudentServiceImpl"/>

Comment: ok so you either use xml or annotations but generally not both, either use auto scanning and give it a base-path so Spring can scan your packages for components, services and repositories. or if you are configuring in an xml file ensure that nowhere in your code you are doing service = new Service(). in spring 3, any instance created via new is not known to Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have a getter and setter for your student service in your StudenBean